# How to export a file in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, jpg

How to export a specific length and width of my work in illustrator?

I made a background asset that's longer than the stage and I don't know how to export it properly.

This is how it looks like in Illustrator,
[image]

when I export it in jpg file as is, I get this,
[image]

the result I wanted is this,
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ticking the "use artboards" option when exporting and set your artboard to the size you want.